# Retrieve given member of variadic class by type

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

here is a recursive class definition :

```
template<class... T>
class Mgr2
{

};

template<class T, class... args>
class Mgr2<T, args...>
{
  Container<T> _container;
  Mgr2<args...> _tail;
public:
  Mgr2() { };
};
```

I'd like to implement the following :

```
Mgr2<int, double> mgr;
mgr.get<int>(); // retrieves the Container<int> element
```

How could I do this? I tried to do several things but failed.... a free function is fine too, and I don't care if the behaviour is undefined if there are 2 "int" in the class defintion for instance

thanks !

Comment: If your library supports the new C++14 [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) you can use a `std::tuple`, either directly or composited into your `Mgr2` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of one way to do this, by restructuring `Mgr2`:

```
template<class T>
struct Leaf {
    Container<T> container;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct Mgr2 : Leaf<Ts>... {    
    template<class T>
    Container<T> &get() {
        return static_cast<Leaf<T>&>(*this).container;
    }
};
```

Having duplicate types result in a compile-time error as soon as `Mgr2` is instantiated.

---

If we want to permit duplicates, or indexing by an integer in addition to indexing by type, we can add an index parameter to `Leaf`:

```
template<std::size_t I, class T>
struct Leaf {
    Container<T> container;
};
```

and adjust `Mgr2`:

```
template<class Seq, class...> struct Mgr2_Impl;

template<std::size_t... Is, class... Ts>
struct Mgr2_Impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
     : Leaf<Is, Ts>... { };

template<class... Ts>
struct Mgr2 : Mgr2_Impl<std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...> {
private:
    template<class T, std::size_t I>
    Leaf<I, T>& do_get(Leaf<I, T>& leaf) { return leaf; }
    template<std::size_t I, class T>
    Leaf<I, T>& do_get(Leaf<I, T>& leaf) { return leaf; }

public:
    template<class T>
    decltype(auto) get() { return do_get<T>(*this).container; }
    template<std::size_t I>
    decltype(auto) get() { return do_get<I>(*this).container; }
};
```

---

If you want to keep your original design, you can use SFINAE or tag dispatch. Showing the former:

```
template<class U>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, T>{}, Container<U>&> get(){
    return _container;
}
template<class U>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<U, T>{}, Container<U>&> get(){
    return _tail.template get<U>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `std::tuple`, and `std::get` from C++14:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Mgr2
{
private:
    std::tuple<Container<Ts>...> _containers;
public:
    Mgr2() {};

   template <typename T>
   const Container<T>& get() const { return std::get<Container<T>>(_containers); }

   template <typename T>
   Container<T>& get() { return std::get<Container<T>>(_containers); }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/LaMZP4).

If you are stick to C++11, You may write your own `get<T>` in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

I simply found out that it can be easily done like this:

```
template<class... T>
class CptMgr
{
};

template<class T, class... args>
class CptMgr<T, args...>
{
    CptContainer<T> _container;
    CptMgr<args...> _tail;

public:
    template<class U>
    CptContainer<U>& get() { return _tail.get<U>(); };

    template<>
    CptContainer<T>& get() { return _container; };
}
```

Comment: You are using MSVC, aren't you? This code is broken in multiple ways.